# Newly Generated Capacitor Plugin Java Import Errors

Tags: android, android-studio, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I'm trying to create my first Capacitor Plugin for an Ionic app. I used the command

```
npm init @capacitor/plugin
```

to generate it. Then following the instructions [here](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v3/plugins/android) I opened the android folder in Android Studio. My file though has several import errors that I can't figure out how to fix.

[image]

Hovering the red text I get the error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'JSObject'
```

I haven't changed anything from the generated version. I've tried Invalidating Caches and Restarting as well as Clean Project. I have very little experience in Java and creating Andriod Apps. All I know is there there is an import error, but why if the plugin is freshly generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are following capacitor 3 docs but testing on a capacitor 2 project

Comment: Ok, thanks. How can I update the plugin to capacitor 3?

Comment: You need to update your project, not the plugin. Make sure you have @capacitor/android@3.0.0-rc.2 installed

Comment: Ok, didn't have that installed but I just did. Still getting the IntelliSense errors though. I don't have the plugin added to any project yet, I've opened the generated files in Andriod Studio. Do I need to regenerate them for v3?

Comment: If it’s not in any project, did you run npm install?

Comment: Yes, I used -g which to my understanding install it everywhere, correct?

Comment: I mean to run npm install in the plugin folder, it should install all required packages. And no, you shouldn’t use -g on capacitor packages, you install them locally for your projects, not globally